Make a full width table using Borb
I'm trying to reduce the margins of a page using borb, that works, but my Table then is not taking the full width of the page.
Please note that not only Table is shifted and not covering the full width, HorizontalRule as well etc...
What's the fix for that ?
from decimal import Decimal

from borb.pdf import Document, Page, SingleColumnLayout, PageLayout, Paragraph, Image, PDF


def main():

    # Create document
    pdf = Document()

    # Add page
    page = Page()
    pdf.add_page(page)

    # create PageLayout
    page_layout: PageLayout = SingleColumnLayout(page)

    for i in [Decimal(0), Decimal(16), Decimal(32), Decimal(64)]:

        page_layout._margin_left = i
        page_layout._margin_right = i
        page_layout._margin_bottom = i
        page_layout._margin_top = i

        # Add Paragraph
        page_layout.add(Paragraph(f"padding set at {int(i)}"))
        page_layout.add(
            FixedColumnWidthTable(
                number_of_columns=3, number_of_rows=3
            )
        )

    with open("output.pdf", "wb") as out_file_handle:
        PDF.dumps(out_file_handle, pdf)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Here's what I would like.

It is unclear what you expect. Setting the margins on PageLayout will force everything added to the PageLayout to respect those margins. In my opinion, that is working as designed.

What I want is to reduce the page margins so all the content is wider. With a margin left and right of 5, I'd like the table box to start a 5 and end at page.width - 5. Same for the horizontal rule.

Your link takes me to a "log in to switch drive" page.

Should be fixed now, sorry about that.

disclaimer: I am the author of borb
The "issue" you are running into is that borb applies a sensible default for margins (on Image objects).
Looking at the (constructor) code in Image:
            margin_bottom=margin_bottom if margin_bottom is not None else Decimal(5),
            margin_left=margin_left if margin_left is not None else Decimal(5),
            margin_right=margin_right if margin_right is not None else Decimal(5),
            margin_top=margin_top if margin_top is not None else Decimal(5),

So you explicitly need to pass margin_left=Decimal(0) (and other) to have an Image whose total distance to the page-boundary is exactly as specified.
Update (for adding Table objects):
The main issue is that PageLayout also keeps track of the available width, which is used by a FixedColumnWidthTable but not by the Image.
So, your code needs to change that as well.
from decimal import Decimal

from borb.pdf import Document, Page, SingleColumnLayout, PageLayout, Paragraph, Image, PDF, FixedColumnWidthTable


def main():

    # Create document
    pdf = Document()

    # Add page
    page = Page()
    pdf.add_page(page)

    # create PageLayout
    page_layout: PageLayout = SingleColumnLayout(page)

    for i in [Decimal(0), Decimal(16), Decimal(32), Decimal(64)]:

        # change margin
        # IMPORTANT:    you are not supposed to do this after having created
        #               the PageLayout
        page_layout._margin_left = i
        page_layout._margin_right = i
        page_layout._margin_bottom = i
        page_layout._margin_top = i
        page_layout._column_widths = [Decimal(595) - i - i]

        # Add Paragraph
        page_layout.add(Paragraph(f"padding set at {int(i)}"))
        page_layout.add(
            FixedColumnWidthTable(
                number_of_columns=2, number_of_rows=3
            ).add(Paragraph("Lorem"))
            .add(Paragraph("Ipsum"))
            .add(Paragraph("Dolor"))
            .add(Paragraph("Sit"))
            .add(Paragraph("Amet"))
            .add(Paragraph("Consectetur"))
        )

    with open("output.pdf", "wb") as out_file_handle:
        PDF.dumps(out_file_handle, pdf)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Which outputs the following PDF:


I just tried with a Table but this still doesn't do what I want sorry. The code above still output 4 tables which have exactly the same size, while I would want the Table with padding 0 to be as wide as the page, while the one with padding 64 should be less wide. I have added a link to the original post to show what I would like if that helps..

I updated the code. The example works for Image objects because the Image never needs to know the full (available) width, whereas the Table does need to know that. And the code-snippet did not update that information in the PageLayout.

That works now, thank you very much !
